Why am I not able to create the react agent using create_react_agent()?
What am I doing wrong here ?
import streamlit as st 
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq 
from langchain_community.tools import DuckDuckGoSearchRun 
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_react_agent 
from langchain_community.callbacks.streamlit import StreamlitCallbackHandler 
from langchain import hub 
import os  
from dotenv import load_dotenv 
load_dotenv() 

os.environ['GROQ_API_KEY'] =  os.getenv("GROQ_API_KEY") 
 
search=DuckDuckGoSearchRun(name="Search") 
prompt=hub.pull("hwchase17/react") 
 
 
st.title(" LangChain - Chat with search") 

 
if "messages" not in st.session_state: 
    st.session_state["messages"]=[ 
        {"role":"assisstant","content":"Hi,I'm a chatbot who can search the web. How can I help you?"} 
    ] 
 
for msg in st.session_state.messages: 
    st.chat_message(msg["role"]).write(msg['content']) 
 
if prompt:=st.chat_input(placeholder="What is machine learning?"): 
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role":"user","content":prompt}) 
    st.chat_message("user").write(prompt) 
 
    model=ChatGroq(model_name="Llama3-8b-8192",streaming=True) 
    tools=[search] 
    agent = create_react_agent(model, tools, prompt) 
 
    search_agent = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools) 
 
    with st.chat_message("assistant"): 
        st_cb=StreamlitCallbackHandler(st.container(),expand_new_thoughts=False) 
        response=search_agent.invoke(st.session_state.messages,callbacks=[st_cb]) 
        st.session_state.messages.append({'role':'assistant',"content":response}) 
        st.write(response) 

The error is
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'input_variables'
File "/path/to/langchain/agents/react/agent.py", line 114, in create_react_agent

prompt.input_variables + list(prompt.partial_variables)

I was trying to create a simple Agent made through create_react_agent

It is not clear where exactly in your code the error pops up; please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Your prompt variable in the if condition:
if prompt:=st.chat_input(placeholder="What is machine learning?"):

is conflicting with the prompt you have pulled from the hub:
prompt = hub.pull(...)

Please fix that by changing the name of either of them.
The error clearly says that you are sending the prompt with the wrong datatype to agent = create_react_agent(model, tools, prompt).
Try this:
.
.
.
prompt_from_hub = hub.pull(...)
.
.
.
agent = create_react_agent(model, tools, prompt_from_hub)
.
.
.

Also, before this please confirm once that the prompt_from_hub is not a string.
